# Importing accessibility options in recent versions of ubuntu

Tags: accessibility

I'm new to this forum, but without further redo, here's the question:
Being blind, I have to use a screen reader, in this case, Orca.
Now, everything works wonderfully untill I try to open an electron app, or a QT app.
In Fedora, and Arch Linux, I found out that if you place some lines in the .bash_profile and xinetrc files respectively, accessibility will be enabled.
In Ubuntu, though, when I put those lines, nothing happens.
I'll paste the lines below:

```
export GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
export GNOME_ACCESSIBILITY=1
export QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
export QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON=1
export ACCESSIBILITY ENABLED=1
```

Does anyone know how this could be fixed in recent versions of Ubuntu, like 20.04 and 20.10?
Thing is, without these options, things like Chrome become totally non usable, although they are.
Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *hirsute* hippo [21.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 21.04 is 22 April 2021 (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/hirsute-hippo-release-schedule/18539) when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: Hirsute Hippo is the current development version of Ubuntu, and questions about it are considered off topic in this site. I am modifying your question to suit it for Ubuntu 20.04 and 20.10, which would make it on topic on this site (and the same solution should in principle work for 21.04, but that is currently not supported on this site). Also, I don't know if this issue is a bug of Ubuntu 21.04 (then it should be reported in the bug tracker instead), or if this issue is present in previous versions of Ubuntu too (which would make it a perfectly valid question on this site).

Comment: If there is a bug, as *hirsute* (what will be 21.04 on release) is currently in *test & fix bugs* stage, this is the best time to get issues fixed, so please use a bug tracker OR use a #ubuntu+1 site where someone maybe able to help you to file a bug if needed, or provide support if you're not reporting a bug. FYI:  this isn't a forum, https://ubuntuforums.org/ is that and they do have a #ubuntu+1 area

Comment: Actually, it's a thing in 20.10 as well, sa far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

For electron apps, you need `ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED=1` (you're missing an underscore)